# Accesses DB2 with entity framework 6 on visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, db2, entity-framework-6, add-in

I'm trying to access DB2 V10 over z/OS via visual studio 2015 and entity framework 6.

After some research i found some promising article - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0903linqentity/

However the example used is for 2010 and the same Add-in is not getting installed for 2015.

Is there any better way of doing this with the combination of VS 2015 + EF6?
Am i missing anything?

**Note** : I don't have the luxury of using third part software's to accomplish the task.

I have tried to install "IBM Database Add-ins" (acquired from the above link itself). This was not successful and below is the installation log details for your reference (if this helps)

```
Property(C): GENERIC_DLG_TITLE = IBM Database Add-Ins for Visual Studio Setup
Property(C): p_DotNetFWInstalled = YES
Property(C): p_DotNetFW11Installed = NO
Property(C): p_DotNetFW20Installed = YES
Property(C): p_DotNetFW40Installed = YES
Property(C): p_vsnet2005Installed = NO
Property(C): VS90_INSTALLDIR = c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\
Property(C): p_vsnet2008Installed = YES
Property(C): VS90_ENVDIR = c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\
Property(C): VS2015_INSTALLDIR = C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\
Property(C): p_vsnet2015Installed = YES
Property(C): VS2015_ENVDIR = C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\
=== Logging stopped: 18/04/2016  12:17:08 ===
MSI (c) (24:A4) [12:17:08:000]: Product: IBM Database Add-Ins for Visual Studio -- Installation operation failed.

MSI (c) (24:A4) [12:17:08:001]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: IBM Database Add-Ins for Visual Studio. Product Version: 10.5.600.234. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: IBM. Installation success or error status: 1603.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating an EDMX from a DB2 Database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36548779/generating-an-edmx-from-a-db2-database)

Comment: @Borophyll I have resolved it by doing some R&D. Wish i could have seen your answer earlier. Your post explains it all. The only difference was i am using 2015, so it needed a different add-in. just a clarification, why do we need a license file? what would i miss if i don't install it? Thanks

Comment: In our experience - we were unable to send queries to our z/OS database from a machine that did not have a license file.  It would throw errors every time.  Based on your comment (indicating that you weren't experiencing this), I tried removing the file and there was no issue.  Likely, this was only a requirement for older versions of the driver... we previously were using 9.7 and 10.1 when we had those issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is specifically for VS2015 and EF6 combination.

IBM has released support for VS 2015 recently. Details in below URL

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21973622

We need to install the 'DSDriver' package, and then 'VSAI' from the following URL's

http://www-933.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/selectFixes?parent=ibm~Information%2BManagement&product=ibm/Information+Management/IBM+Data+Server+Client+Packages&release=All&platform=All&function=fixId&fixids=special_35031_DSClients-nt32-dsdriver-10.5.600.232-FP006%3A261152981044664224&includeSupersedes=0

http://www-933.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/selectFixes?parent=ibm~Information%2BManagement&product=ibm/Information+Management/IBM+Data+Server+Client+Packages&release=All&platform=All&function=fixId&fixids=special_35031_DSClients-nt32-vsai-10.5.600.232-FP006%3A397686600281130112&includeSupersedes=0

Then you can hopefully see a data source for connecting DB2 databases.

Comment: FWIW - the DSDriver and VSAI links above refer to 32 bit solutions.