# How to setup IBM DB2 9.7 to work with Entity Framework 6 and Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, .net-4.5, db2-9.7

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 to develop an ASP.NET MVC application on a Windows 7, 64-bit machine and I want to connect to an IBM DB2 9.7 database using Entity Framework 6 (Code-First).

**Background**

I've found a number of articles online that indicate that the `IBM Data Server Driver` package and the `IBM Visual Studio Add-In` are required in order to use DB2 with Entity Framework 6 (although most of the articles appear to be referencing DB2 version 10.5). I have installed the `IBM Data Server Driver` package 32-bit and 64-bit versions, and the `IBM Visual Studio Add-In` (only 32-bit appears to be available), but a DB2 provider does not appear when I attempt to create the ADO.NET Entity Framework Code-First connection.

[image: Visual Studio 2015 Entity Framework Data Source]

**Install Files**

I installed the following files in the order listed:

1. [IBM Data Server Driver Package - Windows 32bit](https://www-945.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/selectFixes?source=dbluesearch&product=ibm%2FInformation%20Management%2FIBM%20Data%20Server%20Client%20Packages&release=9.7.*&platform=Windows%2032-bit,%20x86&searchtype=fix&fixids=*dsdriver*FP011&function=fixId&parent=ibm/Information%20Management)
2. [IBM Data Server Driver Package - Windows 64bit](https://www-945.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/selectFixes?source=dbluesearch&product=ibm%2FInformation%20Management%2FIBM%20Data%20Server%20Client%20Packages&release=9.7.*&platform=Windows%2064-bit,%20x86&searchtype=fix&fixids=*dsdriver*FP011&function=fixId&parent=ibm/Information%20Management)
3. [IBM Data Server Driver for ODBC and CLI (32-bit) - Windows 32bit](https://www-945.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/selectFixes?source=dbluesearch&product=ibm%2FInformation+Management%2FIBM+Data+Server+Client+Packages&release=9.7.*&platform=Windows&searchtype=fix&fixids=*odbc_cli*FP011&function=fixId&parent=ibm/Information%20Management)
4. [IBM Data Server Driver for ODBC and CLI (64-bit) - Windows 64bit](https://www-945.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/selectFixes?source=dbluesearch&product=ibm%2FInformation+Management%2FIBM+Data+Server+Client+Packages&release=9.7.*&platform=Windows+64-bit,+x86&searchtype=fix&fixids=*odbc_cli*FP011&function=fixId&parent=ibm/Information%20Management)
5. [IBM Database Add-Ins for Visual Studio - Windows 32bit](https://www-945.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/selectFixes?source=dbluesearch&product=ibm%2FInformation+Management%2FIBM+Data+Server+Client+Packages&release=9.7.*&platform=Windows+32-bit,+x86&searchtype=fix&fixids=*vsai*FP011&function=fixId&parent=ibm/Information%20Management)

**Process**

After installing the IBM Data Server Driver package, I opened the `Default DB2 and Database Client Interface Selection Wizard` app for my DB2 client install and set the default configuration to the `Default IBM database client interface (ODBC/CLI driver and .NET data provider) copy`.

Then, I extracted the zip file for the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the `IBM Data Server Driver for ODBC and CLI` to the IBM folder in the C:\Program Files\ and C:\Program Files (x86)\ directories. I opened an elevated command prompt, navigated to the bin folder inside the extracted `clidriver` folders, and ran the following command:

```
db2cli install -setup
```

Finally, I installed the `IBM Visual Studio Add-In`. After installing it, I opened a new MVC project in Visual Studio 2015 and installed the Entity Framework 6 provider for DB2 using Nuget. Then I right-clicked on `Models` and clicked `Add | New Item | Data | ADO.NET Entity Data Model | Add`. In the subsequent window, I clicked on `Code First from database`. In the next window, I clicked `New Connection`. This is where I arrived at the screen shot I provided above.

For reference, I tried a number of different permutations of the above steps without any luck.

**Questions**

1. The documentation for IBM Fix Pack 11 indicates that it works with my database version (9.7.09)...is the documentation wrong?
2. Am I missing a step that's preventing the provider from appearing in the list?
3. Does the IBM Visual Studio Add-In not work with Visual Studio 2015 despite the articles I've found that suggest otherwise?
4. Is the fact that I have a DB2 client installed part of the problem? (I don't really want to uninstall it if it isn't)

**Reference Articles**

1. [Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2015 Support](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=3722e479-9aaf-4711-bdf0-de14c14ad210)
2. [IBM Driver not recognized as supporting Entity Framework 6](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=992874e7-39b4-4b67-aefb-6a0d23b8ee60)
3. [Installing IBM data server clients and drivers (Windows)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.install.doc/doc/t0007315.html)
4. [Getting Started with IBM Entity Framework 6 Database First using MVC 5 (LUW,IDS,zOS and IBM i Servers) on Windows 10](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/96960515-2ea1-4391-8170-b0515d08e4da/entry/Getting_Started_with_IBM_Entity_Framework_6_Database_First_using_MVC_5_on_Windows_10?lang=en)
5. [DB2 ODBC CLI driver Download and Installation information](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21418043)
6. [VS 2015 support announcement](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=12ed045b-7b15-403b-8afb-bdb1158a9773)
7. [Accesses DB2 with entity framework 6 on visual studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36694433/accesses-db2-with-entity-framework-6-on-visual-studio-2015)
8. [Working with Entity Framework 6.0 ON IBM Informix V11.10+ in Visual Studio 2015](https://dondeetan.com/2016/11/30/working-with-entity-framework-6-0-on-ibm-informix-v11-10-in-visual-studio-2015/)
9. [Code-Based Configuration of EF6 Provider for IBM Data Servers (DB2 for i, z/OS, LUW and IDS) in ASP .NET 5 Applications](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/96960515-2ea1-4391-8170-b0515d08e4da/entry/Code_Based_Configuration_of_DB2_EF6_Provider_in_modern_EF_Applications?lang=en)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We use IBM i Access Client Solutions to get the .Net DB2 provider.

Unfortunately, this is not freely downloadable.

IBM i Access Client Solutions

https://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/access/solutions.html

> IBM i Access Client Solutions - Windows Application Package for Windows operating systems.
>
> Features include:
>
> Connectivity to DB2 for i using ODBC, .Net, and OLE DB
>
> Programming Toolkit for accessing IBM i system objects
>
> Support for TLS/SSL connections
>
> AFP printer driver

[IBM DB2 .Net provider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yn4t9.png)

Comment: This does not make the driver appear in the list.